# I get this error : java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

```
Process: com.example.sivancohen.rateapp, PID: 2830
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
ComponentInfo{com.example.sivancohen.rateapp/com.example.sivancohen.rateapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.RatingBar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(android.widget.RatingBar$OnRatingBarChangeListener)' on a null object reference
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.RatingBar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(android.widget.RatingBar$OnRatingBarChangeListener)' on a null object reference
at com.example.sivancohen.rateapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:56)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
atcom.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
05-14 08:48:37.301 2830-2830/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 2830 SIG: 9
```

Here is my activity code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    RatingBar ratingBar;
    Button btn;
    /**
     * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
     * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
     */
    private GoogleApiClient client;

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String userName = intent.getStringExtra("userName");
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                "Hello, " + userName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        ratingBar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
            public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating,
                                        boolean fromUser) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Your Selected Ratings  : " + String.valueOf(rating),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });


        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                float rating = ratingBar.getRating();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Selected Ratings  : " +
                        "" + String.valueOf(rating), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

      /*  FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show()
            }
        });
*/
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, new electric_fragment()).commit();


        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_electric) {
            fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, new electric_fragment()).commit();
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_Clothing) {
            fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, new clothing_frag()).commit();
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_baby) {
            fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, new baby_fragment()).commit();
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_shoes) {
            fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, new shoes_fragment()).commit();
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client.connect();
        Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
                Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
                "Main Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
                // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
                // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
                // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
                Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
                // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app deep link URI is correct.
                Uri.parse("android-app://com.example.sivancohen.rateapp/http/host/path")
        );
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.start(client, viewAction);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
                Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
                "Main Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
                // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
                // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
                // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
                Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
                // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app deep link URI is correct.
                Uri.parse("android-app://com.example.sivancohen.rateapp/http/host/path")
        );
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.end(client, viewAction);
        client.disconnect();
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Cross check your question once before you posts. you are using a view that never been initialised.

Answer (score 2):

The rating bar that you are using is not initialized. you need to create an instance and connect it with your xml and  then use ratingBar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener()
write the following line in on create method before using listener

```
 ratingbar = findViewById(R.id.yourratingbarid)
```

Comment: hay . thank u for the answer but it is not workin .. Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.RatingBar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(android.widget.RatingBar$OnRatingBarChangeListener)' on a null object reference
                                                                                  at com.example.sivancohen.rateapp.MainActivity.addListenerOnRatingBar(MainActivity.java:78) at com.example.sivancohen.rateapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:44)     can u understand why?